# How to auto-increment the version in AppxManifest.xml when appx is created using MakeAppx tool?

Tags: uwp, appx, appxmanifest, makeappx

I created appx package using makeappx.exe. Also I did the changes on Jenkins so that on each build I could have appx as output. Now on each build I am getting appx with same version number as this version is set in AppxManifest.xml  I want to increment the version of appx package on each build. How to do so?

Answer (score 1):

If you use a Debug version, try this step:

1. map file

MakeAppx.exe need a map file to finish the work, most of the information are included in this file:
obj\x64\Debug\package.map.txt

Open it, it the 2nd line, it refer to a file:
bin\x64\Debug\Core\AppxManifest.xml

2. AppxManifest.xml

Open this file, you can find this information in line 10:

Modify the version number, then pack your project like this:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.19041.0\x64\MakeAppx.exe" pack /l /h sha256  /f ".\obj\x64\Debug\package.map.txt" /o /p .\AppPackages\test.msix

The the test.msix file version number changed!

3. Automatic change version number

Save the version number in some where(like a file), and before you call MakeAppx.exe, increase the number and update it in the AppxManifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

The version can be updated in `Package.appxmanifest` of the project before every time it is built. For example:

```
<Identity Name="3ec95549-...7a30bb0" Publisher="CN=publisher" Version="1.2.0.0" />
```

After the project build, you could find the version in `AppxManifest.xml`. But you could just edit the `AppxManifest.xml` to update the version before package.

`MakeAppx.exe` defined the package version depend on the version inside `AppxManifest.xml`.`MakeAppx.exe` doesn't have command to re-set the package version for creating an app package. You may not update the version through `MakeAppx.exe`.

But if you create an app bundle, you can specifies the version number of the bundle by `/bv` command of `MakeAppx.exe`. Details please reference "Create an app bundle section" of [Create an app package with the MakeAppx.exe tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/create-app-package-with-makeappx-tool#using-makeappxexe).